# Python 2: Garbage collection cannot fully free the list of 1 million ints. No problems with 10 million ints

Tags: python, memory-management, garbage-collection

Consider the following program:

```
import gc
from psutil import Process
import sys

def get_resident_set_size():
    return Process().memory_info()[0]

def fun():
    l = []
    for i in xrange(int(sys.argv[1])):
        l.append(i)
    print "RSS in function: %s" % get_resident_set_size()
    return l

gc.collect()
print "RSS after start: %s" % get_resident_set_size()
fun()
gc.collect()
print "RSS after gc: %s" % get_resident_set_size()
```

The final resident set size is different depending on the list size:

```
$ python rss.py 1000000
RSS after start: 10936320
RSS in function: 43479040
RSS after gc: 18251776

$ python rss.py 10000000
RSS after start: 10932224
RSS in function: 336773120
RSS after gc: 11059200

$ python rss.py 100000000
RSS after start: 10985472
RSS in function: 3269484544
RSS after gc: 11112448
```

According to http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/tutorial/python-memory-management.html#internal-memory-management, longer list should increase the resident set size (RSS) forever. 
So why if the list has 1 million entries, ~7 MB are never returned to the system, but for larger lists (10M, 100M) garbage collector frees all the memory perfectly? 
This is 100% reproducible on Linux and Python 2.7.6.

The behaviour is getting weirder if I use random strings instead of ints. If I use xrange in fun as previously, the memory gets freed properly:

```
def get_random_string(size):
    return ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits) for _ in range(size))

def fun():
    l = []
    for i in xrange(int(sys.argv[1])):
        l.append(get_random_string(5))
    print "RSS in function: %s" % get_resident_set_size()
    return l


$ python rss-strings-xrange.py 10000000
RSS after start: 11300864
RSS in function: 579231744
RSS after gc: 11743232
```

But if I use range in the main loop, around 250 MB of memory is not freed:

```
$ python rss-strings-range.py 10000000
RSS after start: 11218944
RSS in function: 824963072
RSS after gc: 257474560
```

It looks like the list generated by range() wasn't freed, but why? As shown above list of integers can be freed completely.

Comment: The garbage collector doesn't free memory to return to the OS; it frees memory to be re-used within the Python interpreter. What I *think* is happening is that Linux will reclaim unused memory from a process (or at least request that process return the memory) after some minimum amount of memory is allocated, and the threshold isn't reached when allocating "only" 1,000,000 ints.

Comment: Thanks. That sounds reasonable.
But why  doesn't Python return garbage-collected memory into OS in case of strings and range?

Comment: It's not specific to strings and range. It's more efficient for the interpreter to hold on to the memory itself in case it needs it later than to return it and have to ask for more. Getting more memory from the OS is relatively expensive, so you want to avoid it where possible.